# Cookies not being saved in browser / If they are saved, they arrive as null to the server

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, jwt, token

I have an issue with http-only cookies using express.js. I'm working on an app where the frontend runs on localhost:5173 and my backend on localhost:3000. For the first try I managed to make the cookies saved by the browser, but in any subsequent requests the req.cookies were null.

In order to achieve this, state here is my router:

```
res.cookie('accessToken', response.jwtToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 20,
      });

      res.cookie('refreshToken', response.refreshToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
      });
      res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' });
```

**Please note that I have the `credentials:include` on the frontend in both the login as well as the subsequent request fetch, I have also tried to use axios, with `withCredentials: true`, didn't change a single thing. **

So after some time I thought maybe the issue is that I have two different ports and that its not https, so I went with the easiest thing I could think of and set up a custom domain with ngrok, so my frontend runs on `frontend-rdg5.ngrok.io` my backend runs on `backend-rdg5.ngrok.io` and I changed my router to create the cookies like this:

```
 res.cookie('accessToken', response.jwtToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: true,
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 20,
      });

      res.cookie('refreshToken', response.refreshToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: true,
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
      });
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
      res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
      );
      res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        'https://frontend-rdg5.ngrok.io'
      );
```

In this setup unfortunately the set-cookies appear in the response header,but they are not stored in the cookie storage. My middlewares are in the right order, I have cors middleware set up in both cases, in the non-ngrok scenario:

```
const expressApp = express();
  expressApp.use(
    cors({
      origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
      credentials: true,
    })
  );
  expressApp.use(express.json());
  expressApp.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  expressApp.use(cookies());
   ... routes
```

and in the ngrok scenario:

```
 const expressApp = express();
  expressApp.use(helmet());
  expressApp.use(
    cors({
      origin: 'https://frontend-rdg5.ngrok.io',
      credentials: true,
    })
  );
  expressApp.use(express.json());
  expressApp.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  expressApp.use(cookies());
```

Thank you very much in advance for any ideas or help!

Comment: cookies doesn't go to server, they go in client Browser system...

Comment: And from the client browser system how is the server supposed to guess whether there are cookies or not?
Let me rephrase because apparently the example code and description is not enough.
I send a request from the client. The server checks whether the user exists and creates a cookie, which gets sent back to the client. 
THEN the client is going to keep sending those cookies with the upcoming requests, which is not happening. Why? Well that is my question.

Comment: it does not work that way. Server cookies mechanism works by session variables; and JS cookies are only type text. prefer to use an ajax system instead.